# SQL Server 2008 BETWEEN function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, between

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME

SET @d1 = '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
SET @d2 = '2015-12-31 23:59:59.999'

SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00' BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2) 
          THEN 'is between' 
          ELSE 'not between'
    END  AS BetweenOrNotBetween
```

The date I supplied here is 1 msec *later* than the range of the `BETWEEN` function, *yet* on my SQL 2008 server instance, the result is **'is between'** and not the expected **'not between'**...

Is this a bug, or is it a necessary compromise in the design for some reason I'm not seeing?

And yes, as soon as I add even a fraction of a second beyond midnight of 2016-01-01, I get the expected **'not between'** result.

Comment: Try the same thing with `DATETIME2(3)` as your datatype - and it'll work. As of SQL Server 2008, I'd recommend using `DATETIME2(3)` instead of `DATETIME` whenever you can

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at documentation for [datetime type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.110).aspx). In section `Rounding of datetime Fractional Second Precision` you will find the explanation to your issue:

> datetime  values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007
>   seconds, as shown in the following table.

This means that if you have 1 millisecond, it is actually rounded to 0 milliseconds, so your result is `is between`. Unfortunatelly this is how `datetime` data type works, there is not much you can do about this, unless you can use other data type, like `datetime2`.

Comment: That stinks like rotten meat! So how is a body to get all the vals in a calendar year, up to the final millisecond? Surely, it's possible, but it must be kludgy.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon  `DateTime2` or `DateTimeOffset` gives you that flexibility

Comment: Thanks for the answer dotnetom.  So it's the "necessary compromise" then.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the code below, you'll see that the problem is the datetime type. Look at the documentation about datetime and your doubt will be solved!

```
DECLARE @d1 datetime2
DECLARE @d2 datetime2

SET @d1 = '2015-01-01 00:00:00.00'
SET @d2 = '2015-12-31 23:59:59.999'

SELECT CASE WHEN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00.00' BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2 ) THEN 'is between' 
       ELSE 'not between'
       END  AS BetweenOrNotBetween
```